# Retrieve geocodes from Google API and append to original table - python

Tags: python, google-maps, geocoding

I am trying to retrieve the geocodes of a bunch of addresses through the Google geocoding API and append them to my table with addresses.

After spending two days reviewing the internet I coulnd´t find any simple way of doing while it shouldn´t be that hard. I am specially having problems parsing the json output and append it to my original table.
I use python 3.5 on windows

I originally got the data from a database which I added to a dataframe in python. But to paste it here it was easier to convert it to a dictionary and back to a dataframe:

```
    data_dict={'street': {0: 'ROMULO', 1: 'SAN BARTOLOME', 2: 'GARBI', 3: 'SAN JOSE'},
 'concat': {0: '3+ROMULO+CALLE+ALMERIA',
  1: '5+SAN BARTOLOME+CALLE+TOLEDO',
  2: '48+GARBI+CALLE+CASTELLON',
  3: '30+SAN JOSE+CALLE+SANTA CRUZ DE TENERIFE'},
 'number': {0: '3', 1: '5', 2: '48', 3: '30'},
 'province': {0: 'ALMERIA',
  1: 'TOLEDO',
  2: 'CASTELLON',
  3: 'SANTA CRUZ DE TENERIFE'},
 'region': {0: 'ANDALUCIA',
  1: 'CASTILLA LA MANCHA',
  2: 'COMUNIDAD VALENCIANA',
  3: 'CANARIAS'}}
```

Back to dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

table=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
```

Now I retrieve the data from the Google geocoding API:

```
import requests
import json

key="MyKey"
jsonout=[]
for i in table.loc[:,'concat']:
    try:
        url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&key=%s" % (i, key)
        response = requests.get(url)
        jsonf = response.json()
        jsonout.append(jsonf)
    except Exception:
        continue
```

I get this output:

```
jsonout=[{'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '3',
      'short_name': '3',
      'types': ['street_number']},
     {'long_name': 'Calle Rómulo',
      'short_name': 'Calle Rómulo',
      'types': ['route']},
     {'long_name': 'Adra',
      'short_name': 'Adra',
      'types': ['locality', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Almería',
      'short_name': 'AL',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Andalucía',
      'short_name': 'AL',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Spain',
      'short_name': 'ES',
      'types': ['country', 'political']},
     {'long_name': '04770', 'short_name': '04770', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
    'formatted_address': 'Calle Rómulo, 3, 04770 Adra, Almería, Spain',
    'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 36.7593, 'lng': -2.97818},
     'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
     'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 36.76064898029149,
       'lng': -2.976831019708498},
      'southwest': {'lat': 36.7579510197085, 'lng': -2.979528980291502}}},
    'partial_match': True,
    'place_id': 'ChIJG39VNzNOcA0R2f8Ek3E12AY',
    'types': ['street_address']}],
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '5',
      'short_name': '5',
      'types': ['street_number']},
     {'long_name': 'Calle de San Bartolomé',
      'short_name': 'Calle de San Bartolomé',
      'types': ['route']},
     {'long_name': 'Toledo',
      'short_name': 'Toledo',
      'types': ['locality', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Toledo',
      'short_name': 'TO',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Castilla-La Mancha',
      'short_name': 'CM',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Spain',
      'short_name': 'ES',
      'types': ['country', 'political']},
     {'long_name': '45002', 'short_name': '45002', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
    'formatted_address': 'Calle de San Bartolomé, 5, 45002 Toledo, Spain',
    'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 39.8549781, 'lng': -4.026267199999999},
     'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
     'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 39.85632708029149,
       'lng': -4.024918219708497},
      'southwest': {'lat': 39.85362911970849, 'lng': -4.027616180291502}}},
    'partial_match': True,
    'place_id': 'ChIJ4bse1aALag0RJ5RxxfyDxUI',
    'types': ['street_address']}],
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '48',
      'short_name': '48',
      'types': ['street_number']},
     {'long_name': 'Carrer de Garbí',
      'short_name': 'Carrer de Garbí',
      'types': ['route']},
     {'long_name': 'Peníscola',
      'short_name': 'Peníscola',
      'types': ['locality', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Castelló',
      'short_name': 'Castelló',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Comunidad Valenciana',
      'short_name': 'Comunidad Valenciana',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Spain',
      'short_name': 'ES',
      'types': ['country', 'political']},
     {'long_name': '12598', 'short_name': '12598', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
    'formatted_address': 'Carrer de Garbí, 48, 12598 Peníscola, Castelló, Spain',
    'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 40.3634529, 'lng': 0.3963583},
     'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
     'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.3648018802915,
       'lng': 0.397707280291502},
      'southwest': {'lat': 40.3621039197085, 'lng': 0.395009319708498}}},
    'partial_match': True,
    'place_id': 'ChIJHVNHcelGoBIRogILRMno_wk',
    'types': ['street_address']},
   {'address_components': [{'long_name': '48',
      'short_name': '48',
      'types': ['street_number']},
     {'long_name': 'Carrer Garbí',
      'short_name': 'Carrer Garbí',
      'types': ['route']},
     {'long_name': 'Vila-real',
      'short_name': 'Vila-real',
      'types': ['locality', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Castelló',
      'short_name': 'Castelló',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Comunidad Valenciana',
      'short_name': 'Comunidad Valenciana',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Spain',
      'short_name': 'ES',
      'types': ['country', 'political']},
     {'long_name': '12540', 'short_name': '12540', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
    'formatted_address': 'Carrer Garbí, 48, 12540 Vila-real, Castelló, Spain',
    'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 39.955829, 'lng': -0.110409},
      'southwest': {'lat': 39.9558231, 'lng': -0.1104261}},
     'location': {'lat': 39.9558231, 'lng': -0.110409},
     'location_type': 'RANGE_INTERPOLATED',
     'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 39.9571750302915,
       'lng': -0.109068569708498},
      'southwest': {'lat': 39.9544770697085, 'lng': -0.111766530291502}}},
    'partial_match': True,
    'place_id': 'EjRDYXJyZXIgR2FyYsOtLCA0OCwgMTI1NDAgVmlsYS1yZWFsLCBDYXN0ZWxsw7MsIFNwYWlu',
    'types': ['street_address']}],
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '30',
      'short_name': '30',
      'types': ['street_number']},
     {'long_name': 'Calle San José',
      'short_name': 'Calle San José',
      'types': ['route']},
     {'long_name': 'Santa Cruz de la Palma',
      'short_name': 'Santa Cruz de la Palma',
      'types': ['locality', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Santa Cruz de Tenerife',
      'short_name': 'TF',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Canarias',
      'short_name': 'CN',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Spain',
      'short_name': 'ES',
      'types': ['country', 'political']},
     {'long_name': '38700', 'short_name': '38700', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
    'formatted_address': 'Calle San José, 30, 38700 Santa Cruz de la Palma, Santa Cruz de Tenerife, Spain',
    'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 28.6864347, 'lng': -17.7624433},
     'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
     'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 28.6877836802915,
       'lng': -17.7610943197085},
      'southwest': {'lat': 28.6850857197085, 'lng': -17.7637922802915}}},
    'partial_match': True,
    'place_id': 'ChIJ8ZFx6__rawwRV3dc118gEgE',
    'types': ['street_address']},
   {'address_components': [{'long_name': '30',
      'short_name': '30',
      'types': ['street_number']},
     {'long_name': 'Calle San José',
      'short_name': 'Calle San José',
      'types': ['route']},
     {'long_name': 'San Andrés',
      'short_name': 'San Andrés',
      'types': ['locality', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Santa Cruz de Tenerife',
      'short_name': 'Santa Cruz de Tenerife',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_4', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Santa Cruz de Tenerife',
      'short_name': 'TF',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Canarias',
      'short_name': 'CN',
      'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
     {'long_name': 'Spain',
      'short_name': 'ES',
      'types': ['country', 'political']},
     {'long_name': '38120', 'short_name': '38120', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
    'formatted_address': 'Calle San José, 30, 38120 San Andrés, Santa Cruz de Tenerife, Spain',
    'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 28.505875, 'lng': -16.1930036},
     'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
     'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 28.5072239802915,
       'lng': -16.1916546197085},
      'southwest': {'lat': 28.5045260197085, 'lng': -16.1943525802915}}},
    'partial_match': True,
    'place_id': 'ChIJsfd-ITjKQQwRjFHLI0XPSok',
    'types': ['street_address']}],
  'status': 'OK'}]
```

What I finally would like to have is my original table dataframe with the lat and lng coordinates

```
   (i['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'],
    i['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'])
```

and the formatted_address from the request.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the json and get it into a pandas dataframe the way you want it? ..

Comment: Yes, but append it to my original table matching the coordinates with the corresponding row. I was already able to get all the lats and lngs in a dataframe, but it seems it doesn´t match the correct rows from my original dataframe. I would also like to add the 'formatted_address' key from the json to check if the address corresponds to my input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy) to do my geocoding, which takes care of parsing the JSON file.

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

googleGeo = GoogleV3('googleKey')

# create a geocoded list containing geocode objects
geocoded = []
for address in mydata['location']:  # assumes mydata is a pandas df
    geocoded.append(googleGeo.geocode(address))  # geocode function returns a geocoded object

# append geocoded list to mydata
mydata['geocoded'] = geocoded

# create coordinates column
mydata['coords'] = mydata['geocoded'].apply(lambda x: (x.latitude, x.longitude))

# if you want to split our your lat and long then do
# mydata['lat'] = mydata['geocoded'].apply(lambda x: x.latitude)
# mydata['long'] = mydata['geocoded'].apply(lambda x: x.longitude)
```

---

Based on the comment you shared, if you are using Google's API without an API key, then it might be beneficial to include a random pause between each geocode call.

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

googleGeo = GoogleV3()

def geocode(address):
    location = googleGeo.geocode(address)
    sleep(randint(5,10))  # give the API a break
    return location
```

Then you use this custom function to do your geocoding

---

Piggybacking on my earlier section, you can even utilize multiple map API services. This is the function I built for one of my projects, utilizing Nominatim's API first, and then falling back on Google's API if Nominatim either returns an error or returns nothing:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim, GoogleV3
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut, GeocoderAuthenticationFailure
from random import randint
from time import sleep

nomiGeo = Nominatim()  # Nominatim geolocator
googleGeo = GoogleV3('myKey')  # Google Maps v3 API geolocator

def geocode(address):
    """Geocode an address.

    Args:
        address (str): the physical address

    Returns:
        dict: geocoded object
    """
    location = None
    attempt = 0
    useGoogle = False  # set to True to use Google only
    while (location is None) and (attempt <= 8):
        try:
            attempt += 1
            if useGoogle:
                location = googleGeo.geocode(address, timeout=10)
            else:
                location = nomiGeo.geocode(address, timeout=10)
                if location is None:
                    useGoogle = True
                    location = googleGeo.geocode(address, timeout=10)
            sleep(randint(5, 10))  # Give the API a break
        except GeocoderAuthenticationFailure:
            print 'Error: GeocoderAuthenticationFailure while geocoding {} during attempt #{}'.format(address, attempt)
            if attempt % 2 == 0:  # switch between services for every attempt
                useGoogle = True
            else:
                useGoogle = False
                sleep(60)
        except GeocoderTimedOut:
            sleep(randint(3, 5))  # Give API a break
            print 'Error: GeocoderTimedOut while geocoding {} during attempt #{}'.format(address, attempt)
    return location
```

Note that I also imported some exceptions specific to the package, because based on my experience with Nominatim, it can sometimes throw random errors and these were the two that I got. Also, from my experiences with the two APIs, Google seemed to be able to interpolate coordinates even if a certain address was not found, whereas Nominatim had to have the address in their database in order to return something.

Comment: Yes! That was much easier. Although it didn´t accept my APIKey since it looks like it only works if you have a premium one. But with googleGeo = GoogleV3() it lets me get a limited amount of coordinates without key.

Comment: Oh purrfect! Then I'd recommend writing a custom function that forces the geocode function to pause a random number of seconds so you're not spamming the API or google may potentially block your IP

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was aware that I shouldn´t make too many calls. I want to do get 300.000+ addresses but I will have to do in several days. I read about the Nominatim geolocator but I prefered google because I guess that in Spain it won´t find as manu addresses as google

Comment: Awesome! I added a couple more stuff to my answer that might be able to address that limitation.

Comment: Anyone else get `GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out`?

Comment: The `Service timed out` can happen which is why I added random pause times and retries.